# Is there a way to prevent new tables being created with the same primary key column name as that on another table?

Tags: oracle, triggers, ddl, oracle19c

I would like to prevent anyone creating a table on which the Primary Key has the same column name as a Primary Key on another table in the same schema.

I'm probably looking for a trigger on create table that can look at the column names of the table being created, check them against all other PK column names, in ALL_CONS_COLUMNS probably, and throw an error if it already exists. How would I do that?

I appreciate that people don't think it's a good idea, but it's not something I've chosen to do and it is something I have to try and do. Here's what I have, am I going along the right track? Is @MT0 correct that I can't do this in such a way that it doesn't mess with data dictionary tables?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_table_trigger
  BEFORE CREATE ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
  IF SYS.DICTIONARY_OBJ_TYPE = 'TABLE' THEN
    IF /* can I grab the PK column name? */ IN ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                                                       FROM all_tables_in_schema
                                                       WHERE column = a_primary_key )
    THEN
      RAISE e_duplicate_pk;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

I'm very junior, I don't get to define CR processes or naming conventions. If you feel it's a stupid question, feel free to move on to another you deem more worthwhile, and perhaps someone else will tell me if it's possible.

Comment: *I'm  probably looking for a trigger* - regardless of the reason, do you want a solution of your task (which someone should develop for you, because you have already described the tool and all the steps) or have a *specific* issue with your current code? Please, clarify your question

Comment: Why would you want to do that? All it does is promote unnecessary use of extra terms or abbreviations in the column names. If you have a table of "things" and a table of "stuff" and you need to have a column in both tables for the name of the object then call the columns in both tables "name" and then if you need to join the tables then use table/column aliases to differentiate.

Comment: @astentx I don't know how to check the names of columns being created in a trigger, also I'm just guessing that this is roughly the way you'd go about it from answers to questions that are not the same. I'm hoping someone who knows what they're doing can elucidate, since I've been googling for ages and haven't found an answer.

Comment: @MT0 I only want it for Primary Key columns, which will be an ID so, s_id and t_id. If someone creates thingimies, I don't want them to be able to re-use t_id.

Comment: it is perfectly ok to have several columns with the same name in different tables. why do you need them to be different?

Comment: @LJWoods What is wrong with having duplicate primary keys and using descriptive aliases in the queries? For (a very basic) example: `SELECT thing.id AS thing_id, stuff.id AS stuff_id FROM thing INNER JOIN stuff ON thing.id = stuff.id` If you have a "thing" table and a "tool" table then if you call one of them "t_id" then how do you know which table it refers to? Just use a coding convention where you use proper aliases and the query will be easy to comprehend.

Comment: @MarEll that's irrelevant. I just need to know IF you can do it, and if so, HOW.

Comment: If you do not know how to obtain column names, then please share your current code and what you've researched so far. Because this requirement is quite strange to provide answers: someone will need to support it and develop in such a setup. I wish not to participate

Comment: @astentx can you please re-open this now I've done what you asked?

Comment: @LJWoods Yes, you can do this with a trigger. But the trigger must be `AFTER` instead of `BEFORE`, otherwise the new table won't be in the data dictionary. Then you can read from `USER_CONSTRAINTS` and `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` to count the number of primary key columns that share the same name, and raise an exception if the number is greater than 1. (I can't post code since the question is closed. Email me if this question never gets reopened and you need the full code.)

Comment: @LJWoods But DDL triggers are tricky and if they're not coded properly can cause serious database problems. It might be safer and easier to solve this problem by creating a scheduled job that periodically checks for these problems and sends an email. Or create a single PL/SQL block to check for problems, and run it during deployments or your CI/CD process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a frame challenge answer.

What you are asking is the equivalent of

> How do I add a trigger to a system-owned data-dictionary table so that I can prevent some DDL statements from working?

Don't.

Let us say that you manage to get the trigger working; how do you know that if the trigger prevents updating the `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` table that all the other dictionary tables will be rolled back and left in a consistent state. You are messing with the data-dictionary and should never do that or you risk leaving your database in an inconsistent and unusable state.

---

If you really want the outcome that tables in the same schema cannot duplicate primary keys then implement a code review process and include that check as part of the review process and then you can have all the code checked and signed off before it is run in the database.